# How to get this name from modal input

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, modal-dialog

```
            <?php 
     $counter = 1;
     foreach ($result as $row) {
        $attributes = array(
                'method' => 'POST'
              );
     $hidden = array('is_submit' => 1);
     echo form_open('update/'.$row['id'],$attributes,$hidden);
     echo"
        <div class='modal fade' id='formModal$row[id]'>
        <div class='modal-dialog'>
            <div class='modal-content'>
                <div class='modal-header'>
                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
                    <h4>Update Customer Details</h4>
                </div>
                <div class='modal-body'>
                    <form>
                        <div class='form-group'>
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type='text' class='form-control input-sm' name='uname' value='$row[name]'>
                        </div><!-- /form-group -->
```

I want to get the value of the name when i click on the update button i get the id for  the required object but , I am not able to get the value from the input like uname(update name) phone number

Comment: Please submit the full code.

Answer (score 0):

May be the half code was not placed correctly.

But the i understood the question and give you a solution.

`var boxInput=$(" .modal").find('input[name="uname"]').val();`

Comment: but i'm not using JavaScript jQuery in this project . Iam using Codeigniter . The issue is when click the update button. I get the id of the instance but can't receive  other data of that instance

Answer (score 0):

I think you start other form inside form,

```
<div class='modal-body'>
<form>                           <!--- try to delete it               
<div class='form-group'>
```